# Chocolateyでインストールがうまくいきません: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator

Tags: powershell, anaconda, chocolatey

Win7 64bitでChocolateyでAnacondaを入れようと思いますが以下のエラーメッセージですすみません。
ググっても原因がよくわからないのでわかる方よろしくおねがいいたします。

```
ERROR: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
```

が原因だと思いますが…
下に全文を載せておきます。

```
PS C:\Users\username> cinst anaconda3
Chocolatey v0.10.11
Installing the following packages:
anaconda3
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading anaconda3 5.1.0... 100%

anaconda3 v5.1.0 [Approved]
anaconda3 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package anaconda3 wants to run 'chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[N]o/[P]rint): Y

ERROR: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
The install of anaconda3 was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - anaconda3 (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

**追記**

ログが膨大なのでエラーメッセージ周辺のみ載せてみます。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```
2018-05-25 10:11:07,959 6148 [DEBUG] - Running 'ChocolateyScriptRunner' for anaconda3 v5.1.0 with packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1', packageFolder:'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3', installArguments: '', packageParameters: '',
2018-05-25 10:11:07,965 6148 [DEBUG] - Running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'
2018-05-25 10:11:07,981 6148 [ERROR] - ERROR: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
2018-05-25 10:11:08,000 6148 [DEBUG] - Built-in PowerShell host called with ['[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = '';[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ''; & import-module -name 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1' -packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1' -installArguments '' -packageParameters '''] exited with '-1'.
2018-05-25 10:11:08,008 6148 [DEBUG] - Calling command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a']
2018-05-25 10:11:08,049 6148 [DEBUG] - Command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a'] exited with '1116'
2018-05-25 10:11:08,135 6148 [DEBUG] - Capturing package files in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3'
2018-05-25 10:11:08,147 6148 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\anaconda3.nupkg'
  with checksum 'F230502247BE21E8E569EDA965FFDA7D'
2018-05-25 10:11:08,155 6148 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\anaconda3.nuspec'
  with checksum 'D1D9708F26914A1D4EA9E3856A5F4CE7'
2018-05-25 10:11:08,160 6148 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'
  with checksum 'A3B03B1A82D971030E2732C652F7B287'
2018-05-25 10:11:08,180 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\anaconda3.5.1.0\.arguments".
2018-05-25 10:11:08,185 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\anaconda3.5.1.0\.extra".
2018-05-25 10:11:08,190 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\anaconda3.5.1.0\.version".
2018-05-25 10:11:08,195 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\anaconda3.5.1.0\.sxs".
2018-05-25 10:11:08,201 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\anaconda3.5.1.0\.pin".
2018-05-25 10:11:08,210 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete directory "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\anaconda3".
2018-05-25 10:11:08,280 6148 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2018-05-25 10:11:08,287 6148 [ERROR] - The install of anaconda3 was NOT successful.
2018-05-25 10:11:08,296 6148 [ERROR] - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2018-05-25 10:11:08,305 6148 [DEBUG] - Moving 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3'
 to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\anaconda3'
2018-05-25 10:11:10,314 6148 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\anaconda3.5.1.0.nupkg".
2018-05-25 10:11:10,330 6148 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2018-05-25 10:11:10,339 6148 [INFO ] - 
2018-05-25 10:11:10,346 6148 [ERROR] - Failures
2018-05-25 10:11:10,354 6148 [ERROR] -  - anaconda3 (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\anaconda3\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2018-05-25 10:11:10,363 6148 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2018-05-25 10:11:10,391 6148 [DEBUG] - Exiting with -1
```

Comment: 出力を見ると `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log` に詳細ログが載っていると書かれていますが、そこに何か詳しい情報が載っていたりはしませんか？

Comment: ログを追記させていただきました。なにかおわかりでしたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: うーん、ちょっと私には分かりませんね……。[anaconda3 の Chocolatey Gallery](https://chocolatey.org/packages/anaconda3) を見てもビルド失敗報告が無いので、何かしらの環境依存な問題だとは思います。パッケージ・メンテナーに連絡を取ってみても良いかもしれません。